# How to add domain name bought from PorkBun to Azure (Azure Web Apps)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, domain-name

Some of us have heard of **Major League Hacking** right? It hosts an event called **Global Hack Week** where we learn and complete challenged to earn points. Now there is a specific challenge that comes every year and that is "**Redeem you GoDaddy domain**", which every year, gives you a free domain from **GoDaddy** (I don't know what is Porkbun, and why the website redirects me there, making us but the domain from PorkBun) which can be used for your use. Now I have followed the same and got myself a domain from PorkBun.
Now coming to *Azure*, I have deployed and hosted a **Web Application** on *Azure* and I want to use a custom domain for my website. So I click on the *Web Server resource*, go to *Overview*, *Add custom domain* -> *+ Add custom domain*. Now what are the next steps? The window that opens has the following contents:

1. Domain Provider
2. TLS/SSL certificate
3. TLS/SSL type (this comes when I select **App Service managed certificate**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the domain and access to the DNS, please follow the steps below:

1. Choose **All other domain services** in the **Add Custom Domain** blade, that will give you an option to type your domain

[image: add custom domain]

2. Once you provide your domain, then you will be requested to add some DNS entries to prove that you own that domain

[image: prove ownership]

3. Follow the steps in how to edit DNS Records at your Domain Provider, for Porkbun it's here https://kb.porkbun.com/article/68-how-to-edit-dns-records

Source

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=root%2Cazurecli